# R markdown- change font size in Knit Word

Tags: r, markdown

I have a chunk of R code that I'm trying to put into a word doc using "Knit Word" in R Markdown.  The R Markdown chunk is as follows:

````
```{r}
all <- readHTMLTable('http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_the_United_States')
```
````

When I Knit Word, however, the line of code goes across three lines because the font size is too large.

I tried using size = 'tiny' as an option in the chunk, but this doesn't change the font size at all.  How can I change the font size of this line of code, so that it is all on one line, without manually changing the font size in the Word doc? Thank you!

Comment: Did you read something suggesting `size="tiny"` would work? (I haven't seen it, please tell me if you did.) Since `knitr` is using `rmarkdown` which is using pandoc, you could first read [pandoc's documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html), specifically for `--reference-docx`. (Unfortunately, this will be for all code blocks within the created docx.)

Comment: The place I read about size = "normalsize" was http://yihui.name/knitr/options/ ("tiny" is another option for size). But it looks like this is only an option for LaTeX. 

Thanks for the pandoc hint.  I was able to figure out how to change the font size of chunks by creating a reference doc, then calling reference_docx: Ref.docx in the heading of my R Markdown file.  The <a href="http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/word_document_format.html#style-reference"> Style Reference </a> topic on the Markdown website was also helpful (and ensuing comments).

Comment: Ahh, good pointer, yes that appears to be for LaTeX only, bummer.